# Dragged external events from div overflow do not appear using FullCalender and FCDraggable

Tags: html, fullcalendar

I am using the FCDraggable version of FullCalendar and everything is working well. However, I would like my external events to be contained in a div with an overflow (ex. JQuery UI Accordian) and dragged onto the calendar. When overflow is on, the external event gets hidden behind the calendar and does not appear until dropped onto the calendar. Without overflow, the external events show fine during the dragging process onto the calendar.

Has anyone else encountered this scenario? I know FCDraggable isn't part of the official release branch of FullCalendar but it works so well except for this one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the overflow property in the jquery ui custom css file for the accordion and that appears to be working now.