# fullcalendar - dragging external events from a long list make event go behind calendar

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I have a select drop-down list which output a list of items using ajax when you choose an option. The problem is that the list of items to be dragged on the calendar is very long. If you scroll the page completely you can go to the last item but you will not be able to see some part of the calendar. So I set the height of the external-events div to 600px and overflow-y:scroll so that you can scroll through the list only without affecting the calendar. The problem is by setting the external-events div to overflow-y:scroll , when I drag an item it does not come out of the div but go behind the calendar. Any idea how to solve this ?? Try the snipet below to see the problem.

I found a solution here: [Dragged external events from div overflow do not appear using FullCalender and FCDraggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917825/dragged-external-events-from-div-overflow-do-not-appear-using-fullcalender-and-f)
but I can't find the css property the guy is talking about.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* initialize the external events
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });

  });


  /* initialize the calendar
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar

    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#external-events {
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#external-events h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#external-events p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666;
}

#external-events p input {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar {
  float: right;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='wrap'>

  <div id='external-events'>
    <div id="showresult">
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
      <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try change to `overflow-x: scroll;`. Refer [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45Lkkqmq/)

Comment: Normally the event should stick on the calendar after it has been dropped. However, changing overflow-x: scroll; does not solve the problem, the event is still going behind the calendar when dragged.

Comment: Have you tried the jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes,the event still goes behind the calendar

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add : helper: 'clone' at draggable function.

$(this).draggable({
   helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* initialize the external events
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      helper: 'clone',  //dragging scroll
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });

  });


  /* initialize the calendar
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar

    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#external-events {
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#external-events h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#external-events p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666;
}

#external-events p input {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar {
  float: right;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='wrap'>

  <div id='external-events'>
    <div id="showresult">
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
      <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
      <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```